# Open InfoWindows on all markers and prevent from automatic closing them?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Currently i can open only 1 infowindow on the clicked marker, but I would like to have infowindows on all markers and not closing them on click.

- How can I have InfoWindows on all markers and prevent from automatic closing them on click ?

Comment: 1 info window at a time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have all info windows shown at the same time.

You can however make a custom marker icon, which will include some text. This icon might look like a marker with info window above. That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new InfoWindow for each marker. The reason one closes as another opens is because they are both using the same object (InfoWindow).

Or at least without any code that's my guess.